# Java EJB @Schedule annotation method is being called twice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, schedule

I am working on a J2EE project that, in short, sends an automated email to a user at a designated time, and allows the user to download files from the webpage that is emailed to them. It works pretty well.

However, my timer method that uses the `@Schedule` annotation is invoked twice. The method always executes immediately at run time (which I don't want), then later at the designated time. I have included code for the Servlet that is loaded when my application is deployed, the Schedule class, and my web.xml file.

`DeployApplicationServlet` class:

```java
package downloadsupport;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import scheduleTimer.ScheduleEmail;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class InitializeApplicationServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/DeployApplicationServlet")
public class DeployApplicationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DeployApplicationServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Web Application Started");

        ScheduleEmail se = new ScheduleEmail();
        se.sendAutomatedEmail();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {

    }
}
```

`ScheduleEmail` class:

```java
package scheduleTimer;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


@Stateless
public class ScheduleEmail {

    @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "10", hour = "12", dayOfWeek = "Wed")
    public void sendAutomatedEmail() {
        // Print Time to console for testing purposes
        System.out.println(new Date());

        // Invoke the SendEmailServlet at the designated time
        try {
            URL emailServlet = new
                URL("http://localhost:9081/downloadsupport/SendEmailServlet");
            URLConnection servletConn = emailServlet.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        servletConn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`web.xml` config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>downloadsupport</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SendEmailServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>downloadsupport.SendEmailServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DeployApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>downloadsupport.DeployApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>DeployApplicationServlet</welcome-file>
        <!--  <welcome-file>SendEmailServlet</welcome-file> -->
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DownloadServet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>downloadsupport.DownloadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!--
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/downloadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 -->
</web-app>
```

Comment: Is it executed ` immediately at run time` or maybe after you call `DeployApplicationServlet`? :-) Why are you instantiating your bean using `new` and why are you calling `se.sendAutomatedEmail()` method?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply. Here was my thought process. When I run my web application, because DeployApplicationServlet is the first welcome-file in my web.xml, it starts up DeployApplicationServlet. I instantiate ScheduleEmail in the doGet method of my DeployApplicationServlet, so when the DeployApplicationServlet is loaded, the sendAutomatedEmail method (the one with the @Schedule annotation) is called, which invokes another servlet (not shown above) that sends an email to a user at a specific time.

Comment: You dont need to instantiate `ScheduleEmail`. Remove these two lines form the servlet and it will work ok. Container is responsible for initializing your bean and calling methods marked with `@Schedule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first, unwanted call is caused by you, not by not working server.

You dont need to instantiate `ScheduleEmail`. Remove these two lines form the servlet and it will work ok.

Container is responsible for initializing your bean and calling methods marked with `@Schedule`

Answer (score 0):

Check your server instance. in case you have 2 nodes in server. then make it one node than ejb timer will work as expected.